# SQL-Server Update SET from SQL Where select is using a field from the table to update

Tags: sql-server

There is nothing wrong with the syntax but I am not getting the right value of ParentCategoryId.
How can I get it?

```
UPDATE Category
SET    ParentCategoryId = (
           SELECT c2.id
           FROM   Category AS c2
           WHERE  c2.OldId = ParentCategoryId -- << how can I get this value
       )
WHERE  OldId IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: Which sql dialect you use here? Why about to use update with join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to give proper two-part column references.**

As it stands, the DB has no idea that the `ParentCategoryId` in the sub-query refers to the outer column.

```sql
UPDATE c
SET    ParentCategoryId = (
           SELECT c2.id
           FROM   Category AS c2
           WHERE  c2.OldId = c.ParentCategoryId
       )
FROM Category AS c
WHERE c.OldId IS NOT NULL;
```

You can also do this as a joined update:

```sql
UPDATE c
SET    ParentCategoryId = c2.id
FROM Category AS c
JOIN Category AS c2 ON c2.OldId = c.ParentCategoryId;
-- WHERE c.OldId IS NOT NULL; -- not necessary as now joined
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your intention correctly, there is no need for a sub-query, you can just have a simple UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE Category
SET    ParentCategoryId = id
WHERE  OldId = ParentCategoryId
AND OldId IS NOT NULL
```